# JFreeChart charts appearance when combined with JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, appearance

I use JFreeChart in my java application to display charts like this one:
[image]

But after creating a report with JasperReports that chart now looks like this:
[image]

And that's not all, this is how a chart looks like inside the first PDF report generated with the app:
[image: first report]

And this is how it looks when I generate a second report, without changing anything, just generating it again:
[image: second report]

This happens again and again, everytime I restart the application. Charts are ok until I create a report. What's happening?

Comment: Does iReport swap out the `GradientBarPainter` for a  `StandardBarPainter` for better printing compatibility?

Comment: Yes, bars are plain solid on reports. But why is that affecting the app and not only the reports?? Does jfreechart have a global list of settings that Jasper Reports is changing?

Comment: I guess Jasper Reports could be changing it in `StandardChartTheme`.

Comment: Thanks @trashgod you were right, I'm going to update the question cause now half of the problem is solved.

Comment: Sorry, no first-hand experience. If you [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188), it would be useful to elaborate on how JasperReports uses chart themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved the edits here as an answer:

#### The theme problem

Thanks to @trashgod I've tried the following line:

```
ChartFactory.setChartTheme(StandardChartTheme.createJFreeTheme());
```

If I use this line before creating charts in my application, reports no longer affect the appearance of them. I think it is enough to put this line just once after report creation.

So now I just have one problem: the first report is different from subsequent reports: charts are different, fonts are bolder and not antialiased...

#### The Problem of the second report

The pdf issue is not caused by jasper reports nor jfreechart. It is a problem of Adobe Reader. This happens when you have more than one instance of Adobe Reader running (for example, when you have two different files opened).
An example of the problem:
[image]
Similar issues:

- http://forums.adobe.com/message/4192938
- http://forums.adobe.com/thread/902298

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`JasperReports`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jasper-reports/info) is using a more prosaic `BarPainter` in it's [`ChartTheme`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartTheme.html), probably to accommodate destinations that handle gradients poorly.

This [forum thread](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115125&p=173754) suggests applying the desired theme directly to the chart. The [`createLegacyTheme()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/StandardChartTheme.html#createLegacyTheme%28%29) method "returns a `ChartTheme` that doesn't apply any changes to the `JFreeChart` defaults. It, or something similar, might be worth a try:

```
StandardChartTheme.createLegacyTheme().apply(chart)
```

Comment: thanks for the effort @trashgod but the problem is not JasperReports or JFreeChart. I've found that the problem is not the report itself, it is Adobe PDF Reader. If I only open one report, it always looks fine. If I open a second report, it always looks bad. No matter which report I'm opening, so it's not the file hehe. Extremely weird. This doesn't happen with Acrobat, it's adobe reader.

Comment: Yep, it's a well-known "destination that handles gradients poorly."

Comment: Two similar issues: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/902298 http://forums.adobe.com/message/4192938 Definetely not a jasperreports/jfreechart problem